# Test connection to database C#

Tags: c#, .net

I've created a small method to test the connection to a database:

```
public bool TestConnection(string provider, string serverName, string initialCatalog, string userId, string password, bool integratedSecurity)
{
    var canConnect = false;

    var connectionString = integratedSecurity ? string.Format("Provider={0};Data Source={1};Initial Catalog={2};Integrated Security=SSPI;", provider, serverName, initialCatalog) 
                                              : string.Format("Provider={0};Data Source={1};Initial Catalog={2};User ID={3};Password={4};", provider, serverName, initialCatalog, userId, password);

    var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

    try
    {
        using (connection)
        {
            connection.Open();

            canConnect = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();                
    }                                         

    return canConnect;
}
```

Despite the method works it doesn t seems right to me. Is any way to test the connection without having to catch the exception?
Is it possible to achieve the same result in a different way?

Comment: You should use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: seems like a reasonable use of exceptions as logic to me, you can omit the catch since its empty and just have a try/finally block

Comment: @Gabriel: Wrong.

Comment: @Slaksi know! thanks - I took your suggestion and what was left of mine (taking away the unused parameter to the catch) and made an answer..

Comment: If you are going to use strings in complex scenarios such as that, I would suggest storing them in constants to make them more easily readable.

Comment: If you want to check whether a connection is able to connect to a database successfully, there is no other way than the one posted by you or @Slaks and as given in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434864/how-to-check-if-connection-string-is-valid But, you can certainly validate whether the connection string is filled with proper values before passing it to the connection object.

Answer (score 14):

It's a little verbose.

I would write

```
try {
    using(var connection = new OleDbConnection(...)) {
        connection.Open();
        return true;
    }
} catch {
    return false;
}
```

You should also use `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder` to properly escape the variables in the connection string.

Comment: Is there a more specific exception that should be getting caught here?

Comment: @WinstonEwert: Good question.  In principal, yes (`OleDbException` or `DataException`), but I'm not sure if I would rely on all providers conforming to that.

Comment: You definitely should NOT be catching all exceptions. Any good provider (like the ones in the framework) will document the exceptions they through. The SQL provider throws just SQLExceptions if its a SQL specific problem. (I tried to find a good reference for my assertion but could not in a quick search ;-)

Comment: @TomWinter: The Framework providers certainly will, but others may not, and unmanaged OleDEb drivers may have their own issues.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote one a little ways back that worked with SQL Server and your current user identity:

```
namespace DatabaseConnectionTester
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool result;

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                result = true;
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var connectionString =
                        "Connect Timeout=10;Pooling=false;Integrated Security=sspi;server=" + args[0];

                    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                catch (DbException)
                {
                    result = false;
                }

                if (args.Length > 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                }
            }

            return Convert.ToInt32(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor it to a TryOpenConnection method, which would be more a more commonly accepted reason to mix logic and error handling (which otherwise is a bad idea). I would think you actually want to use this connection? You don't have to open/close just for confirmation. I also think its a bit verbose to pass in each part of the connection string seperately, but you get the point:

```
    public bool TryOpenConnection(string connectionString, out OleDbConnection connection)
    {
        try {     
            var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString); 
            conn.Open();
            connection = conn;
            return true; 
        } 
        catch (OleDbException exception) {
            connection = null; 
            return false; 
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Good idea ...except that you should use the `using` clause. Set connection to null before `try-catch`; then `return connection != null`

Comment: @ANeves: No...conn.Open() is still in a try-catch. Without proper formatting the following may be a little difficult to read, but I think you will see what I'm talking about :) ...
     `connection = null;
     try {     
            using( var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {
            conn.Open();
            connection = conn; }
        } 
        catch (OleDbException exception) {
            // log failure
        }     
     return connection != null`

Answer (score 1):

```
void Main()
{
    TestConnection(
        "myprovider",
        "myserver",
        "myinitcat",
        "theuser",
        "thepass",
        true);

    TestConnection(
        "myprovider",
        "myserver",
        "myinitcat",
        "theuser",
        "thepass",
        false);
}
public bool TestConnection(string provider, string serverName, string initialCatalog, string userId, string password, bool integratedSecurity) 
{ 
    var canConnect = false; 
    var  csb = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
    csb.Provider = provider;
    csb.DataSource = serverName;
    csb.Add("Initial Calalog", initialCatalog);
    if(integratedSecurity)
    {
        csb.Add("Integrated Security", "SSPI");
    }
    else
    {
        csb.Add("User", userId);
        csb.Add("Password", password);
    }  
    var connection = new OleDbConnection(csb.ToString()); 
    try 
    { 
        using (connection) 
        { 
            connection.Open(); 
            canConnect = true; 
        } 
    } 
    catch
    {
    }
    finally 
    { 
        connection.Close();                 
    }
    Console.WriteLine (csb.ToString());
    return canConnect; 
}
```

Result:

```
Provider=myprovider;Data Source=myserver;Initial Calalog=myinitcat;Integrated Security=SSPI
Provider=myprovider;Data Source=myserver;Initial Calalog=myinitcat;User=theuser;Password=thepass
```

Comment: Use an object initializer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx `var  csb = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder { Provider = provider, DataSource = serverName };`